# Gardening & Landscaping: Weekly Topic Challenge

Tags: discussion, challenge

Jon Ericson has come up with [a wonderful way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work) to boost the amount of questions on the site, and promote activity in topics that may otherwise receive only minimal attention. And it will be a lot of fun. Here's how it works:

1. Suggest topics in the answers below.
2. Next monday, I (or a volunteer) will pick one of the topics and write up a new meta post introducing the challenge for the following week. The topic will be associated with a specific tag (or tag set) so that we can count how many questions were asked. Please use one topic per answer.
3. Anyone who wants to participate asks about the topic of the week.
4. At the end of the week, the organizer post an answer to the challenge with a count of how many questions were asked and anything else they feel like highlighting (like favorite questions or notable achievements).
5. The organizer picks a new topic and starts back on step #2.

Note: It's fine to ask a question you know the answer to, and posting your own question/answer is good. I'll probably do this, but post my question before my answer by a day or so, to get more input.

You can add topics to this list at any time, and if(when) we run out, this challenge series ends. Have fun, folks!

Comment: I'm writing this as a comment rather than answer because it's sort of a plan-ahead recommendation. I think a seed-starting challenge would do well in a month or so. Many people, including me, will be starting seeds indoors and I think the topic will attract good quality questions/answers.

Answer (score 2):

Bulbs are commonly planted in Spring and Fall/Autumn, and ‐ depending on where you live ‐ one of those seasons will be upon us before we know it. Let's have a challenge about [bulbs](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bulbs).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of the [status-completed](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) challenges, in order of age:

#### 2014

- November 3 - 10: [terminology](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) -  **[Weekly topic challenge: terminology [completed]](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/602/weekly-topic-challenge-terminology-completed)**
- November 10 - 17: [seed-saving](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seed-saving) -  **[Weekly topic challenge: seed-saving [completed]](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/605/weekly-topic-challenge-seed-saving-completed)**
- November 17 - 24: [harvesting](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harvesting) - **[Weekly topic challenge: harvesting [completed]](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/609/weekly-topic-challenge-harvesting-completed)**
- November 24 - December 1: [overwintering](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwintering) - **[Weekly topic challenge: overwintering [completed]](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/612/weekly-topic-challenge-over-wintering-completed)**
- December 1 - 8: [tools](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) -  **[Weekly topic challenge: tools [completed]](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/614/weekly-topic-challenge-tools-completed)**
- December 8 - 15: [succulents](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/succulents) - **[Weekly topic challenge: succulents [completed]](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/617/weekly-topic-challenge-succulents-completed)**
- December 15 - January 5, 2015: [pruning](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pruning) - **[Weekly topic challenge: pruning [completed]](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/621/weekly-topic-challenge-pruning-completed)**

#### 2015

- January 5 - 12: [trees](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trees) - **[Weekly topic challenge: trees [completed]](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/627/weekly-topic-challenge-trees-completed)**
- January 12 - 19: [bulbs](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bulbs) - **[Weekly topic challenge: bulbs [completed]](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/630/weekly-topic-challenge-bulbs-completed)**