# Weekly topic challenge: terminology [completed]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, challenge

I made a [post](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge) asking for topic ideas for the challenge, and the highest scoring [suggestion](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge/596#596) is for [terminology](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology).

So, we're going to build our base of terminology questions. These can be closer to

> What is the term for [behaviour]?

like [Why are strawberries cooled before planting, and what is a term for this procedure?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/13346/why-are-strawberries-cooled-before-planting-and-what-is-a-term-for-this-procedu), or more like

> What does [term] mean?

an example of that could be [What is a perched water table?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/13774/what-is-a-perched-water-table)

Please use the tag [terminology](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) when posting questions for this challenge, and remember to keep the site quality at a good level.

Next week, on November 10, I will tally up the results to see how we did, in an answer below this post. Feedback? Comment below this post or find me in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/546/the-garden-shed). Have fun!

Comment: This is a great opportunity to improve and establish the question-answer base of [gardening.SE]! Will definitely try to ask a few questions or two later the week :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the week that the challenge ran, we received 6 questions tagged [terminology](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology):

- [What is apical dominance?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14536/what-is-apical-dominance)
- [What's the difference between annual, biennial, and perennial plants?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14537/whats-the-difference-between-annual-biennial-and-perennial-plants)
- [What's the difference between corms, bulbs, and tubers?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14545/whats-the-difference-between-corms-bulbs-and-tubers)
- [What is the term for this pruning technique that causes stubby, clublike branches?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14559/what-is-the-term-for-this-pruning-technique-that-causes-stubby-clublike-branche)
- [How can I identify the “type” of a rose if I don't already know what it is?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14563/how-can-i-identify-the-type-of-a-rose-if-i-dont-already-know-what-it-is)
- [What is the term for removing weeds from bodies of water?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14568/what-is-the-term-for-removing-weeds-from-bodies-of-water)

These questions have attracted 9 answers. Here are the participants:

**Askers:**

[image: profile for Unihedron at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for standgale at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for J. Musser at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

**Answerers:**

[image: profile for laughing-jack at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for omen at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for bamboo at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for j-musser at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for goleztrol at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for sue at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for tony-piazza at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]