# Weekly topic challenge: seed-saving [completed]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, challenge

I made a [post](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge) asking for topic ideas for the challenge, and the next open [suggestion](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge/598#598) is for [seed-saving](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seed-saving).

You can ask a question about saving seeds of any type you'd like to learn about, or you can share knowledge you already have. Pick a favorite plant and learn/share how to collect and store the seeds!

Please use the tag [seed-saving](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seed-saving) when posting questions for this challenge, and remember to keep the site quality at a good level.

Next week, on November 17, I will tally up the results to see how we did, in an answer below this post. Feedback? Comment below this post or find me in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/546/the-garden-shed). Have fun!

Comment: I love the idea of a seed-saving tag. I actually looked for one a few weeks ago. I think it's pertinent and will be very helpful for the large number of people in climates where annuals are prevalent and at the end of their season.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the week that the challenge ran, we received 7 questions tagged [seed-saving](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seed-saving)

- [How do you collect and keep cucumber seeds for planting the next year?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14586/how-do-you-collect-and-keep-cucumber-seeds-for-planting-the-next-year)
- [Can I save the seeds of Maiden Grass?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14593/can-i-save-the-seeds-of-maiden-grass)
- [How do I save lilac seeds?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14605/how-do-i-save-lilac-seeds)
- [Can I save the berries from a Big Blue Liriope (Liriope muscari) and plant them next spring?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14615/can-i-save-the-berries-from-a-big-blue-liriope-liriope-muscari-and-plant-them)
- [How can I save seeds from strawberries?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14617/how-can-i-save-seeds-from-strawberries)
- [Can I grow pineapple plants from seed, rather than crowns?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14622/can-i-grow-pineapple-plants-from-seed-rather-than-crowns)
- [How long should I dry fresh seeds from solanaceae, cucurbitaceae and other families, before storing?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14643/how-long-should-i-dry-fresh-seeds-from-solanaceae-cucurbitaceae-and-other-famil)

These questions have attracted 6 answers. Here are the participants:

**Askers:**

[image: profile for matt-s at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for j-musser at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for shule at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

**Answerers:**

[image: profile for ecnerwal at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for fiasco-labs at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for that-idiot at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for j-musser at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for alpar at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]