# Weekly topic challenge: harvesting [completed]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, challenge

I made a [post](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge) asking for topic ideas for the challenge, and the next open [suggestion](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge/598#598) is for [harvesting](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harvesting).

You can ask about harvesting any fruit or veggie.

Please use the tag [harvesting](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harvesting) when posting questions for this challenge, and remember to keep the site quality at a good level.

Next week, on November 24, I will tally up the results to see how we did, in an answer below this post. Feedback? Comment below this post or find me in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/546/the-garden-shed). Have fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the week that the challenge ran, we received 3 questions tagged [harvesting](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harvesting):

- [How does one harvest aloe vera leaves?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14677/how-does-one-harvest-aloe-vera-leaves)
- [How long after full coloring do I harvest grapes?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14688/how-long-after-full-coloring-do-i-harvest-grapes)
- [How often can I harvest coppiced black-locusts?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14690/how-often-can-i-harvest-coppiced-black-locusts)

These questions have attracted 0 answers (as of now). Here are the participants:

**Askers:**

[image: profile for J. Musser at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

**Answerers:**

*n/a*