# Weekly topic challenge: overwintering [completed]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, challenge

I made a [post](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge) asking for topic ideas for the challenge, and the next open [suggestion](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge/606#606) is for [overwintering](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwintering).

Winter is coming in the northern hemisphere, so this is a good, seasonal topic for y'all.

Please use the tag [overwintering](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwintering) when posting questions for this challenge, and remember to keep the site quality at a good level.

Next week, on December 1, I will tally up the results to see how we did, in an answer below this post. Feedback? Comment below this post or find me in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/546/the-garden-shed). Have fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the week that the challenge ran, we received 3 questions tagged [overwintering](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwintering):

- [How can I ensure that hellebores in 6" nursery pots survive the winter?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14714/how-can-i-ensure-that-hellebores-in-6-nursery-pots-survive-the-winter)
- [What's a good way to protect fig trees overwinter?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14717/whats-a-good-way-to-protect-fig-trees-overwinter)
- [What is a desiccant and is it helpful when saving annual Snapdragon seeds for the winter?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14724/what-is-a-desiccant-and-is-it-helpful-when-saving-annual-snapdragon-seeds-for-th)

These questions have attracted 3 answers. Here are the participants:

**Askers:**

[image: profile for niall-c at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for J. Musser at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for sue at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

**Answerers:**

[image: profile for J. Musser at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for ecnerwal at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]