# Weekly topic challenge: tools [completed]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, challenge

I made a [post](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge) asking for topic ideas for the challenge, and the next open [suggestion](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge/603#603) is for [tools](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools).

Winter is coming in the northern hemisphere, and with the slowing down of seasonal gardening activities, more time can be spent looking for appropriate tools for future projects, maintaining/storing current tools, etc.

Please use the tag [tools](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) when posting questions for this challenge, and remember to keep the site quality at a good level.

Next week, on December 8, I will tally up the results to see how we did, in an answer below this post. Feedback? Comment below this post or find me in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/546/the-garden-shed). Have fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the week that the challenge ran, we received 3 questions tagged [tools](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools):

- [What equipment do I need to transplant a 20' tall pin oak?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14757/what-equipment-do-i-need-to-transplant-a-20-tall-pin-oak)
- [Is it possible to turn a tumbler compost too frequently?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14768/is-it-possible-to-turn-a-tumbler-compost-too-frequently)
- [Is it practical to sharpen hedger blades yourself?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14795/is-it-practical-to-sharpen-hedger-blades-yourself)

These questions have attracted 6 answers. Here are the participants:

**Askers:**

[image: profile for J. Musser at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for longdaysjourneyintocode at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

**Answerers:**

[image: profile for ecnerwal at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for kevinsky at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for J. Musser at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for bamboo at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for phlume at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]