# Weekly topic challenge: succulents [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge

I made a [post](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge) asking for topic ideas for the challenge, and the next open [suggestion](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge/611#611) is for [succulents](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/succulents).

From cacti to sedum, euphorbia to crassula, succulents are everywhere. As houseplants, as garden plants, anywhere, ask about succulents. How to care for them, uses for particular species, identification, safety, etc.

Please use the tag [succulents](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/succulents) when posting questions for this challenge, and remember to keep the site quality at a good level.

Next week, on December 15, I will tally up the results to see how we did, in an answer below this post. Feedback? Comment below this post or find me in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/546/the-garden-shed). Have fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the week that the challenge ran, we received 10 questions tagged [succulents](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/succulents):

- [Why does my repotted cactus seem to be dying?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14817/why-does-my-repotted-cactus-seem-to-be-dying)
- [What cacti can grow without cold protection in USDA zone 6b in Pennsylvania?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14819/what-cacti-can-grow-without-cold-protection-in-usda-zone-6b-in-pennsylvania)
- [Why did my Agave plants stop growing shortly after sprouting?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14826/why-did-my-agave-plants-stop-growing-shortly-after-sprouting)
- [What's the best thing to do for a neglected agave?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14831/whats-the-best-thing-to-do-for-a-neglected-agave)
- [How should I treat a badly aphid infested shedding Hoya?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14832/how-should-i-treat-a-badly-aphid-infested-shedding-hoya)
- [Cactus and Succulent in the same pot](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14835/cactus-and-succulent-in-the-same-pot)
- [Is there a temperate climate perennial succulent adapted to wet root conditions?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14840/is-there-a-temperate-climate-perennial-succulent-adapted-to-wet-root-conditions)
- [Can we root prickly pear pads that are sold in grocery stores as a vegetable?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14855/can-we-root-prickly-pear-pads-that-are-sold-in-grocery-stores-as-a-vegetable)
- [What are the white bugs on my Aeonium and how do I get rid of them?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14863/what-are-the-white-bugs-on-my-aeonium-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-them)
- [Will prickly pear thrive under the eaves on the west side of my house?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14880/will-prickly-pear-thrive-under-the-eaves-on-the-west-side-of-my-house)

These questions have attracted 9 answers. Here are the participants:

**Askers:**

[image: profile for harvey at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for J. Musser at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for tom-brendlinger at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for nee-r at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for user2497792 at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for shule at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for tdihp at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for niall-c at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

**Answerers:**

[image: profile for kevinsky at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for srihari-yamanoor at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for J. Musser at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for ecnerwal at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]