# Weekly topic challenge: pruning [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge

I made a [post](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge) asking for topic ideas for the challenge, and the next open [suggestion](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge/618#618) is for [pruning](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pruning).

Please use the tag [pruning](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pruning) when posting questions for this challenge, and remember to keep the site quality at a good level.

Next week, on December 22, I will tally up the results to see how we did, in an answer below this post. Feedback? Comment below this post or find me in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/546/the-garden-shed). Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the week(s) that the challenge ran, we received 8 questions tagged [pruning](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pruning):

- [Should I try to treat a Majesty palm tree with brown holes in the leaves?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14846/should-i-try-to-treat-a-majesty-palm-tree-with-brown-holes-in-the-leaves)
- [How should I prune a cleistocactus that got too tall?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14900/how-should-i-prune-a-cleistocactus-that-got-too-tall)
- [What is a sucker and how does it differ from a water sprout or branch?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14906/what-is-a-sucker-and-how-does-it-differ-from-a-water-sprout-or-branch)
- [How should I prune a common fig for best productivity?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14908/how-should-i-prune-a-common-fig-for-best-productivity)
- [Why the leaves of my guava getting dry and dropping?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14914/why-the-leaves-of-my-guava-getting-dry-and-dropping)
- [Am I pruning my pepper plants optimally?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14989/am-i-pruning-the-my-pepper-plants-optimally)
- [How should I prune a top heavy Jade plant?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/15043/how-should-i-prune-a-top-heavy-jade-plant)
- [Is it really that important to prune deadwood from trees? If so, why?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/15057/is-it-really-that-important-to-prune-deadwood-from-trees-if-so-why)

These questions have attracted 7 answers. Here are the participants:

**Askers:**

[image: profile for joseph-witriol at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for J. Musser at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for that-idiot at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for jalal-rasooly at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for apoc at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for diana at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

**Answerers:**

[image: profile for J. Musser at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for ecnerwal at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for fiasco-labs at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for plantluvr at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for nportelli at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]