# Weekly topic challenge: trees [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge

I made a [post](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge) asking for topic ideas for the challenge, and the next open [suggestion](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge/622#622) is for [trees](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trees).

You can ask about tree care, pruning, planting, or anything. A lot of tree care goes on in winter, because of the drop in other regular landscape maintenance.

Please use the tag [trees](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trees) when posting questions for this challenge, and remember to keep the site quality at a good level.

Next week, on January 12, I will tally up the results to see how we did, in an answer below this post. Feedback? Comment below this post or find me in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/546/the-garden-shed). Have fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the week(s) that the challenge ran, we received 2 questions tagged [trees](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trees):

- [What are these brown, cap-shaped mushrooms on my birch tree?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/16070/what-are-these-brown-cap-shaped-mushrooms-on-my-birch-tree)
- [Can I use 12-6-9 fertilizer sticks for a Ficus Bonsai?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/16105/can-i-use-12-6-9-fertilizer-sticks-for-a-ficus-bonsai)

These questions have attracted 3 answers. Here are the participants:

**Askers:**

[image: profile for sue at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for neeku at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

**Answerers:**

[image: profile for sue at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for J. Musser at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

[image: profile for kevinsky at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]