# Weekly topic challenge: bulbs [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge

I made a [post](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge) asking for topic ideas for the challenge, and the next open [suggestion](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge/628#628) is for [bulbs](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bulbs).

Spring, summer and fall flowering bulbs are a common addition to the landscape, or in the home. Whether it's about optimal-conditions, pest or disease diagnosis/control, planting/care instructions, variety selection, or anything, ask about bulbs this week! Even some vegetables (such as onions and garlic) are bulbs.

Please use the tag [bulbs](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bulbs) when posting questions for this challenge, and remember to keep the site quality at a good level.

Next week, on January 19th, I will tally up the results to see how we did, in an answer below this post. Feedback? Comment below this post or find me in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/546/the-garden-shed). Have fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the week that the challenge ran, we received 1 question tagged [bulbs](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bulbs):

- [Garlic scapes drooping during a cold winter without much snow. Will they survive?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/16127/garlic-scapes-drooping-during-a-cold-winter-without-much-snow-will-they-survive)

This question have attracted 1 answer. Here are the participants:

**Askers:**

[image: profile for longdaysjourneyintocode at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]

**Answerers:**

[image: profile for J. Musser at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange, Q&A for gardeners and landscapers]